# How to show notification on Android Wear device only

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Is there a way to show a notification using NotificationManagerCompat on a wearable only and not in the normal notification area on the phone?

Comment: you will be getting deviceid and devicetype for every device, it will be useful for restricting/sending notification for wear alone.rite?

Comment: sorry, what I mean is my app is for a phone and shows a custom dialog so initially I didn't need to show notifications but now I want to make it show a notification on the watch only, it seems you can only show in both if posting from the phone - or is there an option I can pass to NotificationManagerCompat to tell it to show only on watch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of creating a notification on the phone, send a message from the phone to the wearable using the [Messaging API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html). Then when you receive that message on the wearable, use the same notification API in your wearable app code (instead of in the phone app) - this will raise a notification on the wearable.

Comment: thank you, you confirm what I hoped wasn't the case which is I need to create an app on the wearable itself now as well to do what i need.

Comment: There is a demo called SynchronizedNotifications in the SDK samples that shows exactly how to implement this.

Comment: Heres a direct-link to the sample @WaynePiekarski mentioned for future reference: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SynchronizedNotifications

Comment: For some reason, this sample (SynchronizedNotifications ) doesn't work well for me when testing with the emulator. It only shows notifications on the device, but not on the emulator. The normal sample of notifications ("WearableNotifications") does work well, but it shows on both the device and the emulator. How come? Is it a bug on the emulator?